# How to detect an element that came into view

Tags: jquery

The issue was that I am trying to detect when an element is coming into view so that I can trigger an event to happen on the navigation menu. The event is supposed to add a class via jquery and remove it when it comes out of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
    {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }


    $(window).scroll(function(){

        let anchorTags = ['deals-closed'] // list of all ids

        $(anchorTags).each(function (i, e) {

            if (isScrolledIntoView($(`#${e}`))) {
                $(`a[href="#${e}"`).addClass('active')
            } else {
                $(`a[href="#${e}"`).removeClass('active')
            }
        }) 
    });
})
```

Comment: I'd use the [native intersection observer instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). Less code, more reliable, and no jQuery needed.